# iOS FBSDK combine 'first_name' and 'last_name' to get Full Name - Syntax issues

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to combine two **FBSDKGraphRequest** *parameters* in a single db entry in **Firebase** so that it looks the same as users who Sign Up with Email.

I want to combine Facebooks's "**first_name**" and "**last_name**" into a single "*Full Name*" entry. I've tried every syntax I can imagine but I cant get it to work.

At the moment it looks like this:

```
//.. Code that sets up the parameters and guard statement

let firstname = result["first_name"] as? String,
let lastname = result["last_name"] as? String,
let fullname = result["first_name","last_name"] as? String

//.. Code that saves details to db
```

First name and Last Name works, but as soon as I combine the two it does not execute the guard block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Facebook Graph API has field for Users called "name". It is full name that you need.

But if you want to use firstName and lastName without `guard`, try this:

```
if let firstName = result["first_name"] as? String, let lastName = result["last_name"] as? String {
    var fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

Comment: Using field called "name" was the best solution in my case!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use two separate keys into the dictionary and get one string out. Each key has its own separate string. You probably want to do something like this:

```
guard let firstName = result["first_name"] as? String else {
    // Handle no first name
    return
}
guard let lastName = result["last_name"] as? String else {
    // Handle no last name
    return
}
let fullName = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
```

In other words, you need to write the code that combines the strings, using [string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292). Nothing in the result dictionary is going to do this on its own.

Side note: it seems like you need to gain a better understanding of how Swift dictionaries (and in general, Swift constants, variables, and types) work. I'd recommend digging into the [collection types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) documentation.